Programmatically mapping tree IDs and unique IDs in MeSH
all.
I have a long list of MeSH term IDs, some are tree IDs, like C15.378.100.100, some are MeSH unique IDs(UIs) like D001778. I want a way to link tree IDs to UIs.
Currently, I can search with the tree ID and find the UI in the browser. But I haven't found any way to automatically do this.

I've checked the RH-mesh.owl. not all tree IDs have corresponding UIs.

I also tried the MeSH API. But it gives me wrong terms. For example, the query below should give me a term about blood clot rather than hospital.
curl -X GET "https://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/lookup/details?descriptor=C15.378.100.100" -H "accept: application/json"

I found another interface for retrieval. But this one doesn't include the unique ids (D001778) in the term description: http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/C15.378.100.100


Can you help me find an ID converter?
Thanks!
